# Shopify Plus Checkout.liquid, wait for shipping methods to load

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

On a shopify PLUS store I'm trying to customize the checkout.liquid at the shipping method select page, so far so good, but my script only works after a refresh. This is probably due to the fact that my script runs before the shipping methods are all loaded :(

Is there any event I can listen for, that tells me all shippingmethods have been loaded?

I tried to use the shopify.onCartupdate event, because once the shipping methods are loaded the first one is applied to the checkout by default (added to the checkout total) but unfortunately, and maybe logicallly the checkout does not update the cart for the shipping method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What customization are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I created a carrierservice for dutch shipping option, where the customer can select a pick-up point near them, because these are 10 options I convert the 10 options to 1 and add a dropdown box in that one shipping option named “pick-up point” this is all working, except for the first request. I know JavaScript is far from iDeal, and I wish there was a shipping_method.liquid section

Answer (score 1):

Super late answer however you can use this new snippet.

```
Checkout.$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Inside the call back function you can run any code, or use `window.location` to determine which page you're on specifically. Needs to be run on `checkout.liquid` meaning Plus stores **only**.

Answer (score 0):

Shipping methods are always loaded **AFTER** your checkout.liquid renders. So you cannot affect them. Whatever you are trying to do, you will have to monkey patch in Javascript world. And even then, good luck. I am not sure there is even an event you can subscribe to labelled shippingMethodsReady kind of thing.

Comment: Hi David, Yes I figured as much, so unfortunately I am monkey patching in JavaScript. I created a carrierservice for dutch shipping option, where the customer can select a pick-up point near them, because these are 10 options I convert the 10 options to 1 and add a dropdown box in that one shipping option named “pick-up point” this is all working, except for the first request. I know JavaScript is far from iDeal, and I wish there was a shipping_method.liquid section

Comment: Here is a screenshot, of what I got, the left is the normal shippingoptions display, when I go to checkout, the right one is when I hit refresh, or go back and forward again (looks like the request is then cashed, and then my code works) https://imgur.com/a/mWZJUbp